# Using Renovate Bot Amazon Machine Image (AMI) data source and two different AWS regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, renovate

In my Git repository I have several places where I define Amazon Machine Images (AMI). Unfortunately, AMIs of TEST and INT environment are from the region "eu-central-1" and AMIs of PROD environment are from "eu-west-1". If I search my Git repository for AMIs with Renovate Bot and then look up the latest AMI via the data source, then I can only do this for one AWS Region (environment variable "AWS_REGION").

This works fine with one AWS region, but as soon as I want to update AMIs of two different regions this doesn't work anymore and Renovate Bot even falsifies the AMI of the region I didn't set via environment variable "AWS_REGION". :-(

I successfully use the RegEx Manager with matchStrings and the amiFilter plus the data source amazon-machine-image to find the most recent AMI as described here: https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/datasource/aws-machine-image/

Example renovate.json regEx Manager config:

```
    {
      "fileMatch": [
        "^terraform/environments/.*\\.tfvars"
      ],
      "matchStrings": [
        ".*amiFilter=(?<packageName>.*?)\n(.*currentImageName=(?<currentDigest>.*?)\n)?(.*\n)?.*?(?<depName>[a-zA-Z0-9-_:]*)[ ]*?[:|=][ ]*?[\"|']?(?<currentValue>ami-[a-z0-9]{17})[\"|']?.*"
      ],
      "datasourceTemplate": "aws-machine-image",
      "versioningTemplate": "aws-machine-image"
    }
```

Example Terraform config of TEST/INT:

```
# renovate: amiFilter=[{"Name":"owner-id","Values":["602401143452"]},{"Name":"name","Values":["amazon-eks-node-1.27-*"]}]
# currentImageName=unknown
self_managed_node_linux_ami = "ami-0b9392da889265d8d"
```

Example Terraform config of PROD:

```
# renovate: amiFilter=[{"Name":"owner-id","Values":["602401143452"]},{"Name":"name","Values":["amazon-eks-node-1.27-*"]}]
# currentImageName=unknown
self_managed_node_linux_ami = "ami-05fb5fbb50e08e8be"
```

Unfortunately AWS doesn't bring up a region when I use "aws ec2 describe-images" that I could filter on and set the amiFilter in Renovate Bot config accordingly.

Has anyone of you ever thought of a solution for this?

Thank you in advance :-)

Greetz...
Marcel